# No module named 'encodings' after upgrading to 16.04

Tags: upgrade, python, python3, pip

Hi I upgraded my Ubuntu to 16.04 but whenever I try to run a Python program or pip install (both Python 2.7 or Python 3.5) I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I am a newbie to Ubuntu Linux so please answer accordingly

Comment: Does this only happen when inside a virtualenv?  What if you create a new virtualenv and try to install in that?

Comment: I did what u said @jwodder, It works for Python2 but i need packages for Python3 also

Comment: terminal says 'pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 8.1.1 (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('pip==8.1.2'))' and

 raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==8.1.2' distribution was not found and is required by the application

Comment: pip3 works if i install outside virtualenv

Comment: @EvaristeGalois When you have activated a virtualenv, just use `pip` instead of `pip3`.

Comment: @edwinksl will it install packages for Python3 ? In Ubuntu 15.04 when i used pip it installed for Python2 and when I used pip3 it installed for Python3 I want that feature back

Comment: @EvaristeGalois What are you using to create your virtual environment? `virtualenv`?

Comment: yes... virtualenv

Comment: @EvaristeGalois Running `virtualenv venv` creates a virtualenv named `venv` for Python 2 while running `virtualenv venv -p python3` does the same for Python 3. In both cases, after you have activated the virtualenv, you just need to use `pip`; it will know what version of Python is in your virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks @edwinksl it worked .... actually in Ubuntu 15.04 i used to make virtualenv env and in the environment it would run both the versions of Python

Comment: What do you mean by "it worked"? Do you still see the `ImportError` that you mentioned in your question?

Comment: All problems were resolved after I did what you said @edwinks!

Comment: @EvaristeGalois Sounds good; I will write an answer for people who may have a similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, it looks like you were trying to use `pip3` inside a virtualenv that is set up for Python 2. Note that running `virtualenv venv` creates a virtualenv named `venv` for Python 2 by default on Ubuntu if you don't specify the Python version explicitly.

In any case, if you want to create a virtualenv for Python 2, run:

```
virtualenv venv  # create virtualenv named venv for Python 2
```

If you want to create a virtualenv for Python 3, run:

```
virtualenv venv -p python3  # create virtualenv named venv for Python 3
```

In both cases, after you have activated the virtualenv by running `source venv/bin/activate`, you just need to call `pip` to install Python packages; this still applies for a virtualenv created for Python 3 because `pip` already knows what Python version you are using, so *don't* call `pip3`.

Answer (score 1):

I used `dpkg -S <missing file>` to figure out which package to reinstall...

Then I ran (example):

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libpython2.7-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal
```